# How to proper implement stackexchange api?

Tags: php, stackexchange-api

I have implemented fetching the latest questions with php:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=wordpress&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody
```

And then getting the answers for the specific questions id's.
All of this process run in an hourly cron.

The problem if an answer was added to a specific question my script doesn't catch it.

How can I fetch the latest questions and answers, and in later requests still "catch" new answers ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at *questions* only. If you want to pull both questions and answers, you have two options.

#### Option 1: Two API calls

Using this option, you'll use your existing call to get new questions. You'll also add a call to the [`/answers`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers) end point.

The downside to this is the extra API calls this will generate.

#### Option 2: Use the `/posts` endpoint

Utilize the [`/posts`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts) end point to get both questions and answers. This returned both new questions and answers with a single call.

The downside to this is that it will only return fields that are common to both post types.

Comment: Thanks Andy !
Is there an easy way to get new comments from posts I all ready fetched ? without overload with calls.
Because after a short time I will have a alot of questions and go check each one it's a bit killing no ?

Comment: You can check up to 100 posts at a time. However, you can only get back 100 results per "page", so if each of those 100 posts has 2 new comments, you'd still have to make at 2 calls to the API - one for the first 100 and one for the second 100. There isn't a way to do this any other way.